# Utilizando DataFormatString para dar formato de moneda, no me sale la que deseo

Tags: c#, asp

Cordial saludo. Estoy buscando darle formato a un valor de moneda que presento en el aplicativo. Este es el código con el cual convierto el dato en un valor tipo moneda:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor" DataField="ValorPagar" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

El resultado que me entrega es este:

```
546.590,00 €
```

Mi deseo es que lo muestre de esta forma:

```
$ 546.590
```

Como pueden notar, el símbolo que deseo es diferente y no deseo ponerle decimales.

Agradecemos la ayuda.

Comment: Tiene que ver con la localización. Intenta cambiando [la cultura](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture). Por ejemplo https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xz5Gjj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el formato **{0:$#,##0}** para mostrar el símbolo de dólar a la izquierda de la parte entera del número, el separador que sería una coma **(",")** y tres decimales, donde el último decimal sería el 0.

Por tanto te quedaría como:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor" DataField="ValorPagar" DataFormatString="{0:$#,##0}"/>
```